# Adding leading zeroes to record in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

We have a number in XML that can go up to 3 digits in a large XML file that has to be converted to fixed length text using xslt for loading into another system.

I need to pad this with leading zeros to a length of 3 in the output (which is fixed length text)

Examples:

- 1 becomes   001
- 11 becomes  011
- 250 becomes 250

Please help.

Answer (score 7):

`format-number($n, '000')` should do the trick. Alternatively, `substring(string(1000+$n), 2)`.

Comment: Thanks for that alternative.  Our runtime environment doesn't make format-number() visible, so the alternative was a godsend.